# Clearing unbound data fields and running a query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Background:
I have an access table called Tbl_Party, where the primary key is Party_ID.
I have a form (frmParty) to view the records in Tbl_Party, which displays all relevant fields and has several unbound text boxes. These unbound text boxes are used to filter records via a query I built which is activated b a button on the form. All this works fine.

Problem:
I have created a second button called Clear, which I want to clear all data from the unbound text boxes and re-run the query, which as the fields are now blank would return all records.

I created a sub routine in VBA to clear the data from the unbound text boxes which works fine when called from an event procedure:

```
Private Sub Clear_Click()
    Me.txtBox1 = ""
    Me.txtBox2 = ""
    Me.txtBox3 = ""
    Me.txtBox4 = ""
End Sub
```

The issue I'm having is combining this with re-running the query. I can only think of doing this via a Macro.

The RunCode option in a macro only lets you use functions. I have tried to build a function that calls the sub process, but functions built in the form code aren't recognised by the macro builder and I can't call the sub process from a function built in a module. I have tried building both the function and the sub (exactly as above) in a module, but it then tells me it can't find the fields.

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Comment: There are several ways to go without a macro but directly in VBA: form's requery, control's requery, DoCmd.OpenQuery, etc. However, I am a bit confused as what the query does or exist? It is not the form's recordsource and text boxes are not combo or list boxes that contain row source queries. Please be specific and I can craft a refined answer. Also consider assigning Null instead of "" to textboxes in order to truly clear out their value rather than a zero length value.

Comment: The query is merely used to filter the records by field. So txtBox2 is used against Party_Forename with Like "*" & [Forms]![frmViewParty]![txtBox2] & "*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Me.Requery
```

If the query itself is throwing an error now, probably because it contains an unvalid WHERE-clause try to modify the basic query like this:

```
SELCT ... FROM ... WHERE (1=1) AND (...here goes your txtBox-filtered string...)
```